# javascript replace not replacing string zero {0}

Tags: javascript, str-replace

why below code is not replacing {0}

```
var errorMessage = "Minimum {0} and maximum {1} characters allowed",spec =[1,60], dRegex;
   for(i = 0; i<2; i++){
      
      dRegex = new RegExp("\\{"+i+"\\}","g");
      errorMessage.replace(dRegex,spec[i]);
    }
"Minimum {0} and maximum 60 characters allowed"
```

Comment: The `.replace()` method returns the new string with replacements. It does not change the original string.

Comment: Questions like these can very often be answered by consulting documentation from MDN or some other reliable source. (There are in fact many similar questions about `.replace()` on this site.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set errorMessage. replace doesn't modify the string. It returns the modified string.

```js
var errorMessage = "Minimum {0} and maximum {1} characters allowed",spec =[1,60], dRegex;
   for(i = 0; i<2; i++){
      
      dRegex = new RegExp("\\{"+i+"\\}","g");
      errorMessage = errorMessage.replace(dRegex,spec[i]);
    }
console.log(errorMessage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is already given (strings are immutable, so you have to reassign the value of a replace operation).

Alternatively, you may want to explore [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const specs = [1, 60];
const errorMessage = `Minimum ${specs[0]} and maximum ${
  specs[1]} characters allowed`;
console.log(errorMessage);

// or replace immediately
console.log(
  "Minimum {0} and maximum {1} characters"
    .replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, (a, b) => specs[b])
);
```